# I am unable to create table in MySql (Error 1064)

Tags: mysql-error-1064

While I am creating a table In **MySql**, I am getting an error. I don't know What the problem is, but it will be helpful if I understand the reason behinId it.

Query:

```
create table publish(
    From varcahar(60),
    To varchar(60)
);
```

**ERROR 1064 (42000):** *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'From varcahar(60),To varchar(60))' at line 1*

Answer (score 3):

Several errors:

1.- *From* and *To* are reserverd words you need to escape them

2.- varcahr -> varchar

Final code:

```
create table publish(
    `From` varchar(60),
    `To` varchar(60)
);
```

Comment: This is correct.  Strangely, I could not add backticks in comments like you have them.  Maybe that only works in answers?

Comment: Thank You sir, That Reserved words are the main problem

Answer (score 1):

It says varcahr(60) not varchar(60)

Comment: I have changed it to Varchar(60) but still same error is reporting

Comment: <code>create table publish(`From` varchar(60),`To` varchar(60));</code>

From and To need to be surrounded by quotes...the one next to "1" on your keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Spelling problem

```
create table publish(From varchar(60),To varchar(60));
```

This is the right one. You misspelled `varchar`

And also `From` and `To` are reserved words. Check this [Reserved Words In MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)